# Why can't I access core webapi from xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I have a standard .net2.0 Xamarin forms project that works flawlessly with the asp.net core webapi as long as I start the api from a different VS2017 instance.

If I include it in the Xamarin solution like this:

[image]

It erros out with: Message  "Cannot access a disposed object.\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'."    string

This is the http call:

```
public static async Task<string> PostDataAsync(string url, string json, string baseUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + url, new StringContent(
                    json,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json"));

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

It hits the PostAsync methods, the parameters are correct, but goes immediately to "Catch" with the error mentioned above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Xamarin doesn't use .Net Core, is that your problem?

Comment: Its a separate asp.net core project in a solution.  It should be separate from Xamarin because it is not referenced in the Xamarin project.  Have no idea if it's my problem or not.

Comment: Yes, but Xamarin can't reference a project targetting .Net Core, it can if it's .Net Standard though.

Comment: they are separate projects are not referenced.  The Xamarin calls the asp.net through httpclient.  There is nothing tying the two together and it should stand alone.

Comment: So if it's not referenced at all, how do you expect to use the classes it contains?

Comment: my guess would be there is something different in how you have the host service configured for the standalone project vs the project in the Xamarin solution.